# Is there any separate language to query SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I need to know whether there exists any technology to query both SQL Server and Oracle from single application and single query language.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Tongue-in-cheek aside, most any complex SQL task (and most anything cool) is so vendor-specific.. (but I'm not really sure what the OP is look for)

Comment: Both DBMS products support entry level ANSI SQL and have proprietary extensions.  So you could use ANSI SQL as long as you stick with the lowest common denominator SQL and use parameterized queries and an open API like ODBC or JDBC.  That said, consider using an application framework so the that underlying SQL access is abstracted.

Answer (score 1):

From my limited understanding, and I could be misunderstanding your question, the technology you would use to query both MS SQL Server and Oracle would be:

SQL

...but with different connection strings:

https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/
https://connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: It is likely more than just a just connection string change.  Consider than a simple query that specifies a date literal will be different between SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: Totally valid observation -it was just given the brevity of the OP, I wasn't sure what level of detail was being sought :-)

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL is the procedural language for SQL Server and Sybase; PL-SQL is Oracle's procedural language.

The two databases have relational theory and SQL in common, but they're very different.

Trying to unify two relational database products into one is a fool's errand.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you correctly you want to develop an application that you can switch databases successfully without much effort. If you are developing using Java you can use Hibernate JPA. It makes it very easy to switch your Application from one database to another with minimal changes and without writing a single sql query. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate(NHibernate for dotnet) or equivalent is the only choice.